# OOP - best practice / performance

Tags: performance, oop

My question is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761700/object-oriented-programming-best-practice) one, but slightly different.

Let's say I have a complex system and thousands of the following objects in an Array:

```
abstract class Vehicle {
  // Some vars

  public abstract void draw();
}

class Car : Vehicle {
  // Some vars

  public override void draw() { /* Draw function */ }
}

class Truck : Vehicle {
  // Some vars

  public override void draw() { /* Another draw function */ }
}
```

Is it more efficient to create an external (static) class VehicleManager which contains the draw functions for each sub-class?  In other words: is every object stored in RAM with all its functions or does the compiler optimize the objects so it makes no different?

Comment: Define "more efficient".  When you attempt both approaches and profile the results, what are the performance differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler is very effective, dont worry about this. The definition of class, which includes the body of methods, is copied only once to executable and of course only once to RAM.

For example in Java, it is called ClassPool, you can read more about it [here](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html#pool)